# how can I get day wise count in pandas based on condition

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have data column status, values are like positive, negative, neutral. I can get day wise count using

```
g=df.groupby(by=df['created_at'].dt.day_name()).count()
```

but I need day with positive,negative, neutral count

Answer (score 0):

You should really provide a minimal example of data.

My guess is that you want `value_counts:

```
df.groupby(by=df['created_at'].dt.day_name())['status'].value_counts()
```

Or include `status` as group:

```
df.groupby(by=[df['created_at'].dt.day_name(), 'status'])['status'].count()
```

Comment: thanks you @mozway. how can i get day_name and datetime  from df['created_at'] column.